# Composing partial functions in Scala

Tags: scala, function, partialfunction

I have two partial functions `f1` and `f2` which I want to compose into a new partial function `f` so that `f.isDefinedAt(x)` iff `f1.isDefinedAt(x) || f2.isDefinedAt(x)`. I mean

```
        --
       | f1(x) iff f1.isDefinedAt(x)  
       |
f(x) = |
       |
       | f2(x) iff  !f1.isDefinedAt(x) && f2.isDefinedAt(x)  
        --
```

Is there a way to compose `f1` and `f2` that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use method [`.orElse`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/PartialFunction.html#orElse[A1%3C:A,B1%3E:B](that:PartialFunction[A1,B1]):PartialFunction[A1,B1]) on `PartialFunction`:

```
scala> val f1: PartialFunction[Int, Unit] = { case x if x > 0 => println(s"called f1 with $x") }
f1: PartialFunction[Int,Unit] = <function1>

scala> val f2: PartialFunction[Int, Unit] = { case x if x < 0 => println(s"called f2 with $x") }
f2: PartialFunction[Int,Unit] = <function1>

scala> (f1 orElse f2)(1)
called f1 with 1

scala> (f1 orElse f2)(-1)
called f2 with -1

scala> (f1 orElse f2)(0)
scala.MatchError: 0 (of class java.lang.Integer)
  at scala.PartialFunction$$anon$1.apply(PartialFunction.scala:253)
  at scala.PartialFunction$$anon$1.apply(PartialFunction.scala:251)
  at $anonfun$1.applyOrElse(<console>:11)
  at $anonfun$1.applyOrElse(<console>:11)
  at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVI$sp.apply$mcVI$sp(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
  at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVI$sp.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
  at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVI$sp.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:28)
  at $anonfun$1.applyOrElse(<console>:11)
  at $anonfun$1.applyOrElse(<console>:11)
  at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.apply(PartialFunction.scala:167)
  at scala.Function1$class.apply$mcVI$sp(Function1.scala:36)
  at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.apply$mcVI$sp(PartialFunction.scala:164)
  ... 32 elided
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `PartialFunction`'s [orElse](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/PartialFunction.html#orElse[A1%3C:A,B1%3E:B](that:PartialFunction[A1,B1]):PartialFunction[A1,B1]%20orElse)

`f1 orElse f2`